# React dropzone component not showing thumbnail from base64 url

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm using [React Dropzone Component](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component) to upload files. My component is basically a `field` of `fieldArray` of `redux-form`. When i add a file to the dropzone, it gets passed to the parent `fieldArray` component and gets saved in its state. I am able to show the preview of already saved files.

```
  this.dropzone.files.push(mockFile);
  this.dropzone.emit('addedfile', mockFile);
  this.dropzone.emit('thumbnail', mockFile, mockFile.url);
  this.dropzone.emit('complete', mockFile);
```

But unable to show the preview of newly attached files. I tried to read the file and then set `mockFile.url` to base64 url.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could check if the state of var eventHandlers.thumbnail === null for new files

Comment: I am not quiet sure why do you want to me to check for  `eventHandlers.thumbnail === null`

Comment: because in the doc: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component  eventHandlers has preview argument. maybe you have to specify if you wish to show thumbnail

Comment: So apparently i was setting dataURL as `file.dataUrl` instead of `file.dataURL`.